# Minimum value of the function $\sqrt{(1+1/m)(1+1/n)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization

If $m, n$ are positive real variables whose sum is a constant $k$, then what is the minimum value of $$\sqrt{\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{m}\bigg)\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigg)}$$

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{m}+\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{mn}}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{m+n}{mn}+\dfrac{1}{mn}}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{k+1}{mn}}\ge\sqrt{1+\dfrac{k+1}{\bigg(\dfrac{m+n}{2}\bigg)^2}}$

$1+\dfrac{4(k+1)}{k^2}=\dfrac{k^2+4k+4}{k^2}=\bigg(\dfrac{k+2}{k}\bigg)^2$

So the least value of your desired expression is $\dfrac{k+2}{k}$

Answer (score 3):

By the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), we have:

$$\left(1^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\right)^2\right) \left(1^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right) \ge \left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}}\right)^2\\
\sqrt{\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)} \ge 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}}$$

But we also know by the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) that

$$\sqrt{mn} \le \frac{m + n}{2}$$

or

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} \ge \frac{2}{m + n}$$

So this gives us

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)} &\ge 1 + \frac{2}{m + n}\\
&= 1 + \frac{2}{k}\end{align}$$

with equality at $m = n = \frac{k}{2}$.

Comment: Perhaps you should add, that the mininum $1+\frac{2}{k}$ is actually reached for $m=n=\frac{k}{2}.$

Comment: @gammatester Good point, I always tend to miss that out. Thanks!